# Hyphenation for documents that are a mix of two languages

Tags: adobe-indesign, hyphenation

My primary language is Russian, but most of my documents are a mix of Russian and English paragraphs and sometimes even sentences/words in the same paragraph.

(I use InDesign for my own personal needs. I don't need to send these documents to a "boss" or publisher, and so I'm OK if they look somewhat chaotic, as long as the meaning is clear and the layout is neat.)

The problem that I have is that although I strongly prefer to use hyphenation, for a two-language document the use of hyphenation in fact means that you need to use two sets of styles, e.g. Body_en and Body_ru, TableBody_en and TableBody_ru, and so on.

For a few reasons, I don't like the idea to duplicate any styles. I prefer to use as few styles as possible. And neither I like the idea to apply a different language to certain words, sentences, and paragraphs manually.

The good news is that since English uses Latin alphabet and Russian uses Cyrillic alphabet, and they are completely different (compare the English word **alphabet** and the same Russian word **алфавит**), I can simly merge English and Russian hyphenation dictionary files (quick-and-dirty hack), then choose the English language for all the styles in the document, and then write by using a mix of English and Russian words, sentences, paragraphs, and the text will be hyphenated correctly.

> I use CS6 on 32-bit Windows 7. In my case, the files that should be merged are:
>
> ```
> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\Linguistics\6.0\Providers\Plugins2\AdobeHunspellPlugin\Dictionaries\en_US\hyph_en_US.dic
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\Linguistics\6.0\Providers\Plugins2\AdobeHunspellPlugin\Dictionaries\ru_RU\hyph_ru_RU.dic
> ```
>
> Simply copy everything below the NEXTLEVEL line in the Russian file into the English one.
>
> Paths for other operating systems (Windows 10 64-bit, macOS) and InDesign versions are here:
>
> https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/kb/add_cs_dictionaries.html

This solves the problem, but there is a disadvantage that the language needs to be set to some real language, which is English in my current workflow as I explained above. This looks ugly and for such documents I would prefer to use the "No Language" language instead.

[image]

How is it possible (**if** possible) to hack dictionary-related InDesign files so that a dictionary file that is combination of English and Russian hyphenation dictionaries will work when the language of the text is set to "No Language"?

Comment: Repeat after me. Its not about what you prefer its about how the things work. You probably cant get it under [no language] because that is likely hard coded but try copying your english file under a new name and see if that pops up in the list.

Comment: Ok the instructions how to do this is https://helpx.adobe.com/ie/indesign/kb/add_cs_dictionaries.html you can make a new dictionary named eng-rus or any name you want but not [no language]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why InDesign hyphenate English words even when the language of a paragraph is not English?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/155976/why-indesign-hyphenate-english-words-even-when-the-language-of-a-paragraph-is-no)